# Shell script opening flask powered webpage opens two windows

Tags: python, bash, shell, flask

I'm writing a small locally-running flask powered web app for some coworkers. They aren't super technologically savvy so I'd like them to be able to simply double click a link to run a shell script, which will start the flask server and then pop open the localhost page on their macs.

I've created a simple file `start`:

```
python server.py
open http://localhost:5000
```

But it pops open two webpages - first the localhost (but with an "unable to connect" message) and then the localhost again with it working. So odd!

I tried using the `webbrowser` module in python, but this has the same effect:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    webbrowser.open("http://localhost:5000/")
    app.run()
```

and putting it afterwards:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
    webbrowser.open("http://localhost:5000/")
```

only opens the page after the server is shutdown.

Any ideas? I guess they could just close the non-working page, but it isn't very smooth functionality.

Comment: I need this functionality as well. I was not able to use the answers below. None of them are accepted as well. Did you find a way to get this work?

Answer (score 2):

use threads. See this for a relevant post.

[python webbrowser.open(url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634235/python-webbrowser-openurl)

Answer (score 0):

put `app.run()` in a function and in `'__main__'` start this function as new thread. Then open webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late, but I needed the same functionality and wound up at this page also...

I thought about this a little bit and by process of elimination I tried adding the 
    `use_reloader=False flag`
to my
    `app.run()`.

The problem is now gone, but I can see by the console trace it has turned off the debugger.  If you don't care about that, then this may work...

This is what worked for me...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("open http://localhost:8080")
    app.run(
            '0.0.0.0',
            port=8080,
            debug=True,
            use_reloader=False, # <== use False and get one tab...but no debug output
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
also tried using a different thread
([python webbrowser.open(url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634235/python-webbrowser-openurl))

and using `os.startfile(url)`

got the same result

but when I changed the Debug to false, it opened only one tab as I wanted

`app.run(debug=False)`