# Open browser automatically when Python code is executed

Tags: python, flask, localhost, python-multithreading

I am implementing a GUI in Python/Flask.
The way flask is designed, the local host along with the port number has to be "manually" opened.

Is there a way to automate it so that upon running the code, browser(local host) is automatically opened?

I tried using webbrowser package but it opens the webpage after the session is killed.

I also looked at the following posts but they are going over my head.

[Shell script opening flask powered webpage opens two windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056360/shell-script-opening-flask-powered-webpage-opens-two-windows)

[python webbrowser.open(url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634235/python-webbrowser-openurl)

Problem occurs when html pages are rendered based on user inputs.

Thanks in advance.

```
import webbrowser

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:2000/')
    app.run(port=2000)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use timer to start new thread to open web browser.

```
import webbrowser
from threading import Timer

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

def open_browser():
      webbrowser.open_new("http://127.0.0.1:5000")

if __name__ == "__main__":
      Timer(1, open_browser).start()
      app.run(port=2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

**I'd suggest the following improvement to allow for loading of the browser when in debug mode:**
*Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476701/10521959), will only load the browser on the first run...*

```
def main():
    
    # The reloader has not yet run - open the browser
    if not os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"):
        webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:2000/')

    # Otherwise, continue as normal
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=2000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476701/10521959

Answer (score 0):

It opens two tabs of the browser. Also you are running the application on port 2000 while opening browser at port 5000.