# Dash hello World doesn't show anything

Tags: python, plotly-dash, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to get started with Dash but even the hello World example doesn't show up on two different laptops under Windows 11 started from within Visual Studio 2022

"my" code

```
# https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial
from dash import Dash, html

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Hello World')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If I 'Start without debugging' the following appears in the command window
[image: app started without debugging]

If I 'Start with debugging' I get [image]

and if I start with `app.run(debug=True)` I don't get any further than
[image]

Examples I found that should display a figure in a browser but those do not work either.

I also tried

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

What am I missing that makes that I don't see any output?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but it sounds like you are waiting for some "output" to be printed to the terminal or opened automatically where you can see the contents of your app. To view your Dash app, use the link that it says it's running on in the terminal, which in your case is http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (port 8050 on your local machine).

Comment: Thanks, this helped. So it means I have to open the page in the browser myself. That is (of course) not what I want so I have to find out how to open that automatically.

Comment: I found it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697716/how-to-automatically-open-a-website-when-launching-the-dash
I didn't find that yesterday